# Accesing kwargs in DeleteView generic view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm creating a DeleteView which needs to access to kwargs outside of the methods, like this:

```
class DeletePost(DeleteView):

    """
    Delete a post. Post deletion is only reserved to space
    administrators or site admins.
    """
    context_object_name = "get_place"
    success_url = '/spaces/' + kwargs['space_name']

    def get_object(self):       
        return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['post_id'])
```

But apparently, arguments and keyword arguments can't be used outside the methods. I also tried to stablish the success_url inside the get method, but django does not recognize it. What can I do to obtain the `space_name` parameter? I'm trying to avoid overriding the view core methods like dispatch() and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `get_success_url()` method.